# Application Gateways, Web apps and private DNS

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm struggling to find the use or benefit of private DNS in web apps with application gateways.

Using terraform I am trying to create a web app with a private connection behind an application gateway.

I am using terraform to create this, and if I set the back end pool to the private IP address changing the host name to the .azurewebsite.net name then it works great.

However whenever I try to create a private DNS and point the back end pool to the web app using the back end pool DNS name, it gives me an error 502.

Here is the code I am using, I have read through a few guides and everyone I read people still seem to be pointing to the IP address rather than the DNS name. A push in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "uks-network" {
  name                = "mrp-uks-tf-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
#  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
    Location    = "UK South"
    terraform   = "True"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mrp-uks-tf-sn-ag" {
  name                                           = "applicationgatewaysubnet"
  resource_group_name                            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  virtual_network_name                           = azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name
  address_prefixes                               = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = "true"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mrp-uks-tf-sn-ws" {
  name                                           = "websitesubnet"
  resource_group_name                            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  virtual_network_name                           = azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name
  address_prefixes                               = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = "true"
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "mrp-tf-uks-dns" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mrp-uks-tf-sn-sql" {
  name                                           = "sqlsubnet"
  resource_group_name                            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  virtual_network_name                           = azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name
  address_prefixes                               = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = "true"
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "uks-webapp-privatendpoint" {
  name                = "webappuks"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.mrp-tf-uks-dns.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.uks-webapp-privatendpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "ukswebapp" {
  name                  = "${azurerm_app_service.uks-webapp.name}-dnslink"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.mrp-tf-uks-dns.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.id
  registration_enabled  = false
}


#Create Private Endpoints for UKS app service
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "uks-webapp-privatendpoint" {
  name                = "uks-webapp-privatendpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.mrp-uks-tf-sn-ws.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "uks-webapp-privatendpoint-com"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_app_service.uks-webapp.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
  }
}


#Create Private Endpoints for UKS app service
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "uks-webapp-privatendpoint" {
  name                = "uks-webapp-privatendpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.mrp-uks-tf-sn-ws.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "uks-webapp-privatendpoint-com"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_app_service.uks-webapp.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "mrp-tf-uks-ag-pip" {
  name                = "mrp-tf-uks-ag-pip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-rqrt"
  redirect_configuration_name    = "${azurerm_virtual_network.uks-network.name}-rdrcfg"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "mrp-tf-uks-ag" {
  name                = "mrp-tf-uks-ag"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.uks-rg.location

  sku {
    name     = "WAF_V2"
    tier     = "WAF_V2"
    capacity = 1
  }

  waf_configuration {
    enabled          = "true"
    firewall_mode    = "Detection"
    rule_set_type    = "OWASP"
    rule_set_version = "3.0"
  }
  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "mrp-tf-uks-ag-ipc"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.mrp-uks-tf-sn-ag.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.mrp-tf-uks-ag-pip.id
  }


  backend_address_pool {
    name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    fqdns = ["${azurerm_app_service.uks-webapp.name}.azurewebsites.net"]
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                                = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled"
    port                                = 80
    protocol                            = "Http"
    request_timeout                     = 1
    pick_host_name_from_backend_address = true
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }
}
```